# How to print the numbers that are in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement, input, user-input

Returning back to learning to code with python.
When I run the code, enter some numbers it will stored as a list by using list() and that list will safe my int(input())

theoreticaly it is just a exercise to guess if its a odd or an even number..
i know, it could be done by simple % 2.

```
line = list(map(int, input("please enter a number: ")))
x_odd = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
x_even = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
if line[-1] in x_odd:
    print("You entered:" + str(line) + ", " + "the number: " + str(line) + " is Odd")
elif line[-1] in x_even:
    print("you entered:" + str(line) + ", " + "the number: " + str(line) + " is Even")
else:
    print("you entered not a number")
```

I except the out of 55 when i enter the number 55 so it shoud be something like this:
You entered: 55, the number: 55 is Odd
what i get is :
You entered:[5, 5], the number: [5, 5] is Odd

it has to be formated into a intiger, but where? 
what can i read, to understand how it works ?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many suggestions but I think this is enough. Just split your code a bit.

```
num = input("Please enter a number") # 55
line = list(map(int, num))
x_odd = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
x_even = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
if line[-1] in x_odd:
    print("You entered:" + num + ", " + "the number: " + num + " is Odd")
elif line[-1] in x_even:
    print("you entered:" + num + ", " + "the number: " + num + " is Even")
else:
    print("you entered not a number")
```

and when you input `55`, the result will be shown like below.

```
Please enter a number 55
You entered:55, the number: 55 is Odd
```

Comment: perfect, this is what i was looking for, but could you please explain what is the reason of spliting the code and adding the
    num

Comment: @MagicalCat Well, line is a list object and if you just print this list, it will show `[5, 5]` and this is not preferred. So, first you need to capture the original input to `num` which will print `55` and use this for your string explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the string:

```
>>> inp = input("please enter a number: ")
please enter a number: 55
>>> print(inp)
55
```

so far so good, but then, map splits the string into a char array and applies the int function to each of those chars individually, converting them to ints, so it seems:

```
>>> m = map(int, inp)
>>> for i in m:
...     print(i)
... 
5
5
```

Since map() expects two args, a function and a collection. It must've split the string for you implicitly, in order to use it as a collection for the map input. Haven't expected that either, honestly :)

You might try to enhance your example with:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> r = reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), list(line))
>>> print("You entered:" + r + ", " + "the number: " + r + " is Odd")
You entered:55, the number: 55 is Odd
```

But then there's still a flaw, this line actually checks whether 5, 5 in your example is a sub-collection of x_odd or x_even:

```
if line[-1] in x_odd:
```

Try 45, will it also tell you that the number is odd? you might probably end up in your else branch. haven't tried that though.

Especially for python the internet has lots of good resources to learn from, on a quick google to find out why reduce didn't work the first time I've tried, I've stumbled upon: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html for example, and found out what was missing immediately. And it seeems like this page has much more stuff to offer, look it up :)

Comment: short answer: use reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), list(line)) to print it as 55 xD

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a single string to `map()` instead of an iterable, it interprets the parameter as a list of characters. So:

```py
line = list(map(int, input("please enter a number: ")))
#line == [5, 5]
```

Not sure why you are passing the input through map. Instead, just do:

```py
line = int(input("Please enter a number"))

if line in x_odd: #Remove the subscript
```

However, if you enter `55` you'll still get "You entered not a number" as output, because `55` is not in `x_odd`.

Instead of building static lists of even and odd numbers, you can just test the input directly:

```py
if line % 2 == 1:
    # line is odd
elif line % 2 == 0:
    # line is even
```

Really you could just use `else` because `int%2` will always either be 1 or 0 (odd or even).

Comment: theoreticaly it is just a exercise to guess if its a odd or an even number.. i know, it could be done by simple % 2.

Comment: Ok, I now see that you are expecting the input to be split, so that you can just check the last digit. As the accepted answer shows, if you need to use the value that was input on its own, you either have to capture it before transforming it (easier) or transform it later (less efficient).